# How to get sum of values in a column using OVER() function?

Tags: mysql, count, window-functions

So I have a table that has stores information per student, their date of birth and the start date of the school. The output needed is **% of students grouped by their age**

The query in Biqquery is written as follows,

```
Select ROUND(100*(Number_of_Students/Total),2) as Percent_Students,Age FROM

(SELECT count(participantname) as Number_of_Students, 
SUM(count(participantname)) OVER() AS Total,
CAST(round(date_diff(startdate, participantdob,day) / 365.25)  AS INT64) as Age 
FROM `ParticipantEnrolment` 

group by Age
order by Age)
```

The output of the inner query is

```
Row Number_of_Students  Total   Age 
1   1                   826     12
2   259                 826     13
3   358                 826     14
4   145                 826     15
5   47                  826     16
6   16                  826     17
```

where Total = 826 is the sum of Number_of_Students

When trying this same query in WorkBench - I am getting a syntax error in the inner query because of OVER() function. The datediff function change is working as intended in mysql. The revised query is below

```
SELECT count(participantname) as Number_of_Students,
SUM(count(participantname)) OVER() AS TOTAL,
ROUND(timestampdiff(DAY,participantdob,startdate)/365.25) as AGE

FROM `ParticipantEnrolment`
group by AGE
order by AGE
```

If i remove the OVER() statement, the query works properly. Unable to figure out what the syntax issue is in this case! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you are running MySQL 5.7 or earlier, where window functions are not supported. You can work around this with a subquery:

```
select 
    count(*) as number_of_students,
    (select count(*) from participantenrolment) as total,
    round(timestampdiff(day, participantdob, startdate) / 365.25) as age
from participantenrolment
group by age
order by age
```

Note that I replaced `count(participantname)` with `count(*)`: assuming that `participantname` is not nullable, both expressions are functionally equivalent, and `count(*)` is more efficient. You can change that back if `participantname` is a nullable column.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Really appreciate the help!